# two hyphens "- -" merged to single — for a word document file name

Tags: windows-xp, browser, windows-explorer, filesystems, hyperlink

Im having a strange issue, there is doc file with following file name "SDH -- 001.doc" which was uploaded to a portal by my friend. But when he tried to download the same download file , link shown has "SDH — 001.doc", two hyphens got merged to one line kinda thing. When he tried to download it, he got an error dialogue box saying "internet explorer was not able to find the site.The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found". But same file when i downloaded, file name converts to underscore "SDH_001.doc" and it downloads. Can anyone help me what is wrong. Is it related to OS? Both of us using win XP and IE 8.

Comment: Try removing the double hyphen unless it is absolutely necessary. Of course this is just a workaround and I don't understand why double hyphens don't work

Comment: i just dont understand..why its working for me..and not in other system..

Comment: It's Word's autocorrect "feature" at work. Turn it off.

Comment: @martineau: What does AutoCorrect have to do with file names?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Sounds like the "portal" is changing the file name. Try a different one (like DropBox).